# How do I split a large changelist in P4

Tags: perforce

I have a very large changelist (~40,000 files) and I need to split it into several smaller changelists so I can view the files contained.  I am aware that I can adjust my p4 preferences to show more files in a changelist, but I need to run commands against the files in the changelist, and when I run the command it hangs and doesn't complete after 18 hours.

I'm running the 2012.2 P4 server.

The command I'm running is:

C:>p4 -u some_user -c some_client revert -k  -c 155530 //...

Thanks

Comment: You say you want to move them into separate changesets, but you also say that you just want to view the files, but then your example has you trying to revert the files.  Which is it?

Comment: I was trying to find a way to identify some files that I could move into a separate changelist so I could operate on (revert) a smaller set of files.  Your solution below addresses how I can do that without identifying particular files in the original large changelist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to move files into a separate changeset, you could do:

```
p4 reopen -c default //some/subdirectory/...
p4 change
```

The above would move a portion of the files into the "default" changeset and then create a new changeset from them.  Or, if you have another changeset to use already, you could of course do:

```
p4 reopen -c NEW_CLN //some/subdirectory/...
```

directly.

If the files you want to split out aren't nicely contained within a subdirectory, a more general approach would be to do:

```
p4 -ztag opened -c OLD_CLN | grep depotFile | cut -d ' ' -f 3 > files.txt
```

to get a list of files opened in that changeset.  Then edit that file so that only files you want to remove from the changeset are listed, and then do:

```
p4 -x files.txt reopen -c NEW_CLN
```

The above calls `p4 reopen -c NEW_CLN` using each of line from `files.txt` as an argument.